# .htaccess doesn't redirect (version 1.6.10)

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, angularjs-routing

To clean my URL from the additional `#!`, I followed these steps:

1. `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
2. `<base href="/">`
3. And then I changed my `href`s to be like this `/home`

The links worked with me, but the problem is when I write the url manually or reload the page.
It returns an error: `Cannot GET /home`.

According to many posts I saw on this site, I added many different `.htaccess` files, and this was the latest one:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested pattern is file and file doesn't exist, send 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# otherwise use history router
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

But none of them worked.
version => `1.6.10`